# Custom customer attribute not showing on frontend

Tags: magento2, frontend, customer-attribute

I've seen this question many times, but all the solutions I've tried didn't work.
I've generated a module that creates three custom attributes in customer's information.
Since I'm new to Magento (Magento 2 especially) I've done this trough Silk
https://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/magento2-module-creator.php

I can see the three attributes fine in the backend, now I need to show them on the frontend so customers can edit them. How can I do that?

This is part of my **CustomerSetup.php** that defines one of the attributes.

```
    $customerSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        'cf',
        [
        'label' => 'Codice fiscale / p.IVA',
        'system' => 0,
        'position' => 104,
        'sort_order' =>104,
        'visible' =>  true,
        'note' => '',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'input' => 'text',          
        ]
    );

    $customerSetup -> getEavConfig() -> getAttribute('customer', 'cf')->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('is_required',0)->setData('default_value','')->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_checkout']) -> save();
```

Now, on **edit.phtml** I've tried something like

```
<?php $block->getCustomer()->getCf() ?>
```

But I can't see anything. Can anyone help? Thanks!

**EDIT**

I've tried the suggestion. I've edited my `CustomerSetup.php` with provided code and created `UpgradeData.php`, coping pasting `InstallData.php`, changing Install with Upgrade and adding a 1 to the version
(should I also change installAttributes in upgradeAttributes?)

```
<?php

namespace Alfabet\ClientiAttributi\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
* @codeCoverageIgnore
*/
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
/**
 * EAV setup factory
 *
 * @var EavSetupFactory
 */
private $eavSetupFactory;

/**
 * Init
 *
 * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.0') < 0){

            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $customerSetup = $objectManager->create('Alfabet\ClientiAttributi\Setup\CustomerSetup');
            $customerSetup->installAttributes($customerSetup);



    }

}
}
```

but even after running `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` i can't see any difference.
I've also tried changing module's version in module.xml, but it causes the site to crash.

Answer (score 0):

check this

try to update cf attribute using `UpgradeData` with below code

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'cf', [
    'type' => 'static',
    'label' => 'Codice fiscale / p.IVA',
    'input' => 'text',
    'required' => false,
    'visible' => true,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'sort_order' => 104,
    'position' => 104,
    'system' => 0,
]);

$eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
    CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
    CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
    null,
    'cf');

$customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'cf')
    ->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_address_edit','adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_register_address','customer_account_edit', 'customer_account_create']
    ])->save();
```

Using customer session to get customer custom attribute

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $cf = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getCf();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, I've tried your solution but it doesn't seems to work. After replacing the piece of code with yours I've ran "php bin/magento setup:upgrade" on comand line, then added your second code in edit.phtml like this "<?php CODE ?>", but i can't see anything.

Comment: Using installData or UpgradeData to create customer attribute. If already created InstallData then use upgradeData to creat attribute with my above code.

Comment: Hi, please see edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it is a typo but just in case.
This won't output nothing:

```
<?php $block->getCustomer()->getCf() ?>
```

`echo` is missing.

Do either

```
<?php echo $block->getCustomer()->getCf() ?>
```

or

```
<?= $block->getCustomer()->getCf() ?>
```